# Two identical Azure apps with different access_token format - one JWT, the other non-JWT

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-web-app-service, openid

When accessing /.auth/me, one app has the access_token in the correct JWT format, but in the other app it's not in JWT format.

This is the valid JWT one: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJu...eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczov...B84ciSKwF2oOre5n`

This is the non-JWT one: `PAQABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrTLy`

The configuration for both apps appear to be identical.

Any idea how to fix the second app to also show JWT access token?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Usually when the authentication flow  configuration has not included ***`resource`***
  as one of the parameter, the  access token does not have form of a (
  JSON Web Token)JWT token token format.
- Please try to include resource with your application Id Uri or
  resource that your application requires . To find the App ID URI, in
  the Azure portal, click Azure Active Directory, click App
  registrations, click the service application, and then click Settings
  and Properties.
- Also set the ***clientId and client secret*** in the request.

In other cases just to access the app service you could use `id_token` or **Bearer** as response_type in authorization header as  Authorization:Bearer "{your-id-token}".

**Reference:**[Oauth 2.0 grant credentials ,Access token request | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret)

You can make use of [azure resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) to edit the    properties of the app service auth to include the resource if not    already included.  See [resource provider and types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types)

To get an access token, please try to set the resource using the Azure Resource Explorer.

1. Navigate to the Resource Explorer from the App Service.
2. Go to  config > authsettings and click on Edit.

Update the additionalLoginParams with ["resource=<Name/ID of the resource>"] and click on PUT.

*For example:*

```
“additionalLoginParams”: [
“resource=https://graph.microsoft.com ”
]
```

Then by saving changes and refreshing the App Service, try again and check that the value for the access token is in the form of a JWT token or not.

[image]

Comment: Ok based on your response, we identified that "loginParameters" is missing from the authsettingsV2 in the second app. After adding this in, the access_token now correctly returns JWT. Wouldn't have figured it out without your help. Thank you.